# Не работает srand(time(NULL));

Tags: c, функции

Не работает функция - srand(time(NULL)); выдаёт ошибку, что идентификатор не определен? При поставлении в функцию просто чисел и переменных работает. Что не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{

  int s = 0;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
  {
    printf("%d\n", 1 + rand() % 2);
  }

  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: include <cstdlib>,<ctime> ?

Comment: @steelhouse, Вы хотя бы пишите, какой компилятор, ОС и что именно не работает.

В Вашем случае (в линуксе), просто компилится (конечно, с флагом -std=c99 или gnu99) с предупреждениями, а дальше вполне себе работает, печатает единички и двойки.

--

А для компиляции без warnings добавьте, как уже говорили, time.h **и возвращаемый main() тип int**.

Comment: буду внимательнее, + указывать ОС и как именно написана ошибка.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не хватает

```
 #include <time.h>
```

Answer (score 7):

`#include <time.h>` же!